# Remove column spacing between bars highchart

Tags: highcharts

Hi Can somebody help out how can i remove the spacing between the stack bars in highchart.

**More white space between bars**

[image]

below is the code I'm using for rendering the chart.
so in x-axis i tried add style but still it's not working as per expectation

```
$('#tempstack').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'bar',
                                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Forms wise progress'
                            },                                
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: stkTemplateName,
                                startOnTick: false,
                                labels: {
                                    rotation: 0,
                                    useHTML: true,
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: 30,
                                    style: {
                                        color: '#000',
                                        font: '12px roboto',
                                        top: '0px',
                                        right: '10px',
                                        'margin-bottom': '0px',
                                        paddingLeft: '0px',
                                        paddingRight: '0px',
                                        paddingTop: '0px',
                                        paddingBottom: '0px',

                                    },

                                    step: 1
                                },
                                lineWidth: 0,
                                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                                gridLineWidth: 0,
                                lineColor: 'transparent',
                                minorTickLength: 0,
                                tickLength: 0,
                                pointWidth: 0.1

                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                gridLineWidth: 0,
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                    text: ''
                                },
                                gridLineColor: '#ffffff',
                                labels: {
                                    enabled: false

                                },
                                minorGridLineWidth: 0


                            },

                            plotOptions: {
                                bar: {
                                    pointPadding: 0,
                                    borderWidth: 0,

                                },

                                series: {
                                    stacking: 'normal',
                                    pointWidth: 20,
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Yet-toStart',
                                data: stkYetToStart
                            }, {
                                name: 'Completed',
                                data: stkCompleted
                            }, {
                                name: 'Inprogress',
                                data: stkInProgress
                            },
                             {
                                 name: 'Ongoing',
                                 data: stkOnGoing
                             }],

                        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decrease the space between the bars by decreasing groupPadding property - also, you set point width, if you have it fixed, you will not be able to change the space.

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    pointPadding: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    groupPadding: 0.01
},
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2c74x5jv/1/

Comment: excellent thanks.. just commented line pointWidth in series tag